# JFileChooser - more options in Load/Save dialog

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I was searching in the past days for a possibility to insert more options into the **JFileChooser**, beside the "normal" name of the file and extension filter.

**Example:**

I have to save EEPROM datafields to the PC in certain text filetypes. The EEPROM contains hex values. I want to be able to choose how I save these hex values: in hex, as they are, or directly in ASCII.
I want to get something similar like in Word >=2010 when saving a file as *pdf. There are extra options you can set.

Here is a picture I made: What I want

[image: What I want]

Thank You!

Comment: So hex is not ASCII?

Comment: It seems to me that you can put that information in the filter

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you can put that information in the filter, however, remember that the JFileChooser is a component that can be placed in your own JDialog.

So you can create a JDialog with, say a BorderLayout, with a JFileChooser at the "center", and a JPanel at the "south". You can add whatever controls you want on the JPanel.

You can either keep the control buttons (Open, Save, Cancel) on the JFileChooser, or hide them by using:

```
fileChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown(false);
```

in which case, you would need to provide your own buttons on the JPanel.

An issue with this technique, is the misalignment of the components in the JPanel with those of the JFileChooser.